# How do I retrieve a value from a row containing two keywords of interest to make a new column on R?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, data-retrieval, nested-for-loop

[I have a data table that looks like this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzicq.png)

And what I basically want to do is to create a new column in the table containing the fold change in my 'readout' for each sample, which will be, for example,

Sample 1 at WEEK 0/Sample 1 at WEEK 0

Sample 1 at WEEK 4/Sample 1 at WEEK 0

Sample 1 at WEEK 14/Sample 1 at WEEK 0

and so on and so forth for all the time points for Sample 1 and then calculate the same thing for the rest of my samples using their respective 'readout' from WEEK 0.

So far, what I have tried is something along the lines of,

```
r
SampleIDs<-as.character(unique(table$ID))

table$FC<-for(i in table[i,]){
for(j in SampleIDs){

if(table[i,"ID"]==j){

    table[i,3]/table[(("WEEK"==0)&("ID"==j)),3]
    }
    }
  }

}
```

When run, the code returns the error,

```
Error in if (table[i, "SampleID"] == j) { : argument is of length zero
```

What I was trying to do was to create a separate vector with unique IDs, and use that in a for function to go row by row to make sure that the row contains the sample with the same ID, and then try to retrieve the cell that contains the data for the sample with ID j **AND** is from WEEK 0 to calculate my fold change value. Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Please show a small reproudcible example  This `("WEEK"==0)&("ID"==j)` could be wrong.  You may need to subset the `table` i.e. `table[["WEEK"]] == 0`

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(new = readout/readout[WEEK == 0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be, we could group by 'ID' and create a new column by dividing the 'readout' with the 'readout' where 'WEEK' is 0

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(new = readout/readout[WEEK == 0])
```

If the 'WEEK' is already orderd

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(new = readout/readout[1])
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, new := readout/readout[WEEK == 0], by = ID]
```

If it is already ordered

```
setDT(df1)[, new := readout/readout[1], by = ID]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$new <- with(df1, readout/setNames(readout[WEEK == 0], unique(ID))[ID])
```

---

Regarding the console showing `+`, it is just a symbol showing the expression is not complete

[image]

This we get in other consoles as well e.g. In Julia, the REPL would not show any symbol but it would give the output after the full expression is completed

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    WEEK = c(0, 4, 14, 24, 0, 4, 0, 4, 14, 24), readout = c(5, 
    6, 7, 8, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 5, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: It worked using base R! If you could, could you give me a break down of what exactly each part of the with() function does? I'd really appreciate it! 

P.S when using the dplyr package functions, every time I hit enter, the console just kept giving me a '+'. No results. Any idea why this might have been?

Comment: @pkt In the console, if you  get `+`, it simply means that the expression is not complete.  here, the expression gets complete only `df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(new = readout/readout[WEEK == 0])` at the end.  Regarding the `base R`, solution, what I did was to extract the 'readout' where the 'WEEK' is 0, and created a named vector with the `unique(ID)` (assuming that there is only a single WEEK 0 for each 'ID', and use that ID as index (`[ID]`) to replicate the values and divide by readout

Comment: @pkt When you do `df1 %>%
+` it expects another expression to complete it.  you need to copy the rest and paste it

Comment: @pkt If you do the same in Julia, there won't be any symbol, but `Julia> 1 + 
       2 +
       3
6`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `for` loop for operations that need to be performed by group. There are functions that help you perform such grouped calculation.

If the data is not already ordered by `WEEK`, you can do that first.

```
df <- df1[with(df1, order(ID, WEEK)),]
```

and then divide `readout` by first value in each group.

This can be done in base R :

```
df$result <- with(df, readout/ave(readout, ID, FUN = function(x) x[1]))
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(result = readout/first(readout))
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, result := readout/first(readout), ID]
```